# A href of webview guide to a new page of UWP

Tags: html, webview, uwp, href

I receive some html data from server, and I try to build a webview to show these data.
Then I need to set some labels to navigate to other page of UWP.

In Windows Phone 8 projects, I can add a label like this to navigate to another page and pass parameters.

[image]

But UWP doesn't support it anymore, so how to navigate to another page and pass parameters??

Comment: You can have the script notify the page that it wants the app to naviage its main page. The [XamlWebView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView) shows how to do this in scenario 4.

Comment: Hi, I have test the sample on Github, it is really helpful.

Comment: But when I click the href label, it doesn't turn into the ScriptNotify method which is really confusing me =(

Comment: I got it!!!Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to help the next person with this problem.

Comment: OK，I will do it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

1.This is the string that webview will navigate to.

```
    "<html>"+
    "<body>"+
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
            "function Click()" +
            "{window.external.notify('parameter1+" + "parameter2"+"...");}" +
        "</script>" +
        "<a href='#' onclick='Click();'>" + "NameOfLabel</a>" +
    "</body>"+
    "</html>";
```

2.Webview add a scriptnotify event in your xaml.

```
<WebView ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"></WebView>
```

3.Get parameter from javascript

```
private async void webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
  //Get the paramter from javascript
  string parameter=e.value;
}
```

4.One more, there is another wat to pass complicate parameters like a class.
But I can't find this artilce, I will add the url later if I find it.